# How to center a div inside a wrapper

Tags: html, css

building a website and need help on how to center this div/image next to another div, but it's inside a wrapper so that when on mobile the div/image goes underneath it. I couldn't figure out what css element to use, so that's why I'm asking. I'm still learning quite a lot, so help is appreciated.

[The website as a demo is here](https://codepen.io/tabogachi/pen/dyJEzaZ)

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("menuBar");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: HebrewRegular;
    background-color: white;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: HebrewRegular;
    src: url("Adobe Hebrew Regular.otf") format("opentype");
    font-weight: bold;
}

.top-container{
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/400/200");
    padding: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.menuBar {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgb(168, 123, 81);
    padding: 30px 40px;
    text-align: left;
  }



  .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .flex-container > * {
    flex:300px;
  }
  
  
  .flex1 {
    background-color: rgba(230, 199, 177, 255);
    width: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 25px;
  }

  .flex2 {
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/400/200");
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class = "top-container"></div>
        <div class = "menuBar" id = "menuBar"> menuBar</div>
        <div class = "mainContent">
            <div class="flex-container">
               <div class = "flex1">
                  <h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ultrices ligula quis nibh dignissim interdum. Proin consequat sem et lacus accumsan aliquam. Vestibulum sodales pretium ex at cursus. Maecenas efficitur finibus dictum. Duis nec quam ultrices, laoreet magna vel, auctor nunc. Sed ultricies lacus consequat velit lacinia, in consequat sapien pretium. Vestibulum sagittis ornare odio at elementum.

                  Vestibulum sodales mauris ut tempor posuere. Nulla orci dolor, porta sed risus viverra, consectetur hendrerit sapien. Phasellus tristique ante augue, id efficitur nisi placerat nec. Nam rhoncus erat quis feugiat sollicitudin. Mauris id magna sit amet risus bibendum pretium. Donec in mauris mi. Morbi dignissim porttitor iaculis. Praesent mollis placerat velit, et blandit nibh venenatis nec. Fusce ut ultrices sem. Nunc eget lectus quis mauris dignissim tempor id placerat tellus. Nam vitae semper augue.

                Quisque rutrum laoreet urna eget posuere. Nulla cursus tincidunt elit et placerat. Duis sed pellentesque magna, non lacinia tortor. Nam nisl dui, rutrum et sollicitudin quis, condimentum quis augue. Aenean varius, nisi at luctus dapibus, diam magna dictum ex, ac sodales ex ex sit amet ligula. Donec pulvinar varius est. Nam vitae rutrum dolor. Donec lacinia, ex nec tempus venenatis, ligula justo dapibus diam, cursus semper augue mauris ac odio. Aliquam a arcu nec lacus rhoncus facilisis. Vestibulum sollicitudin lorem id metus auctor, sit amet ullamcorper mauris fringilla.

                In in erat eu eros volutpat bibendum sit amet fermentum enim. Vestibulum dictum orci sed tincidunt posuere. Donec viverra nunc ut sem viverra, et vestibulum mauris feugiat. Donec imperdiet quam dui, vitae vehicula ipsum hendrerit non. Phasellus nec augue eu erat posuere varius in quis odio. Nunc justo turpis, scelerisque non leo vel, laoreet ornare neque. Donec a neque ac nibh ultricies tristique id vel magna. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque viverra ante in magna fringilla, vel sodales lectus feugiat. Donec sodales, odio eget dictum scelerisque, urna massa fringilla quam, nec pharetra erat dui at massa. Maecenas suscipit velit id scelerisque consectetur. Praesent ac egestas enim. Vestibulum nulla turpis, hendrerit nec sodales vitae, congue at felis. Cras auctor ac quam sed fermentum. Quisque libero est, aliquam ac lorem a, semper molestie mi. Cras suscipit eu erat eget hendrerit. In in erat eu eros volutpat bibendum sit amet fermentum enim. Vestibulum dictum orci sed tincidunt posuere. Donec viverra nunc ut sem viverra, et vestibulum mauris feugiat. Donec imperdiet quam dui, vitae e. Donec viverra nunc ut sem viverra, et vestibulum mauris feugiat. Donec imperdiet quam dui, vitae vehicula ipsum hendrerit non. Phasellus nec augue eu erat posuere varius in quis odio. Nunc justo turpis, scelerisque non leo vel, laoreet ornare neque. Donec a neque ac nibh ultricies tristique id vel magna. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque viverra ante in magna fringilla, vel sodales lectus feugiat. Donec sodales, odio eget dictum scelerisque, urna massa fringilla quam, nec pharetra erat dui at massa. Maecenas suscipit velit id scelerisque consectetur. Praesent ac egestas enim. Vestibulum nulla turpis, hendrerit nec sodales vitae, congue at felis. Cras auctor ac quam sed fermentum. Quisque libero est, aliquam ac lorem a, semper molestie mi. Cras suscipit eu erat eget hendrerit. 
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class = "flex2"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Hope this [Link](https://dev.to/ruphaa/5-ways-to-center-a-div-vertically-and-horizontally-using-css-3i60) will help you!

Comment: Question is unclear, can you provide an image mockup of how you want your elements positioned?

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code as below just removed `flex: 300px` and in flex-container removed `flex-wrap` and in the flex2 container added `width:100%` and changed the `min-height to 200px`

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("menuBar");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: HebrewRegular;
  background-color: white;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: HebrewRegular;
  src: url("Adobe Hebrew Regular.otf") format("opentype");
  font-weight: bold;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/400/200");
  padding: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.menuBar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgb(168, 123, 81);
  padding: 30px 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex1 {
  background-color: rgba(230, 199, 177, 255);
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.flex2 {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/400/200");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* min-height: 300px; added this */
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <meta name="description" content="PLACEHOLDER - CHANGE">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="author" content="Tabogachi">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="keywords" content="Thai, Restaurant, Charm, Food, Good Food, Thai Place, Eat In, Eat-in, Thai Food,">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class = "top-container"></div>
      <div class = "menuBar" id = "menuBar"> suicide 1 2 3 and more along here</div>
      <div class = "mainContent">
          <div class="flex-container">
             <div class = "flex1">
                <h3>  Welcome to Charm Thai Restaurant  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ultrices ligula quis nibh dignissim interdum. Proin consequat sem et lacus accumsan aliquam. Vestibulum sodales pretium ex at cursus. Maecenas efficitur finibus dictum. Duis nec quam ultrices, laoreet magna vel, auctor nunc. Sed ultricies lacus consequat velit lacinia, in consequat sapien pretium. Vestibulum sagittis ornare odio at elementum.

                Vestibulum sodales mauris ut tempor posuere. Nulla orci dolor, porta sed risus viverra, consectetur hendrerit sapien. Phasellus tristique ante augue, id efficitur nisi placerat nec. Nam rhoncus erat quis feugiat sollicitudin. Mauris id magna sit amet risus bibendum pretium. Donec in mauris mi. Morbi dignissim porttitor iaculis. Praesent mollis placerat velit, et blandit nibh venenatis nec. Fusce ut ultrices sem. Nunc eget lectus quis mauris dignissim tempor id placerat tellus. Nam vitae semper augue.

              Quisque rutrum laoreet urna eget posuere. Nulla cursus tincidunt elit et placerat. Duis sed pellentesque magna, non lacinia tortor. Nam nisl dui, rutrum et sollicitudin quis, condimentum quis augue. Aenean varius, nisi at luctus dapibus, diam magna dictum ex, ac sodales ex ex sit amet ligula. Donec pulvinar varius est. Nam vitae rutrum dolor. Donec lacinia, ex nec tempus venenatis, ligula justo dapibus diam, cursus semper augue mauris ac odio. Aliquam a arcu nec lacus rhoncus facilisis. Vestibulum sollicitudin lorem id metus auctor, sit amet ullamcorper mauris fringilla.

              In in erat eu eros volutpat bibendum sit amet fermentum enim. Vestibulum dictum orci sed tincidunt posuere. Donec viverra nunc ut sem viverra, et vestibulum mauris feugiat. Donec imperdiet quam dui, vitae vehicula ipsum hendrerit non. Phasellus nec augue eu erat posuere varius in quis odio. Nunc justo turpis, scelerisque non leo vel, laoreet ornare neque. Donec a neque ac nibh ultricies tristique id vel magna. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque viverra ante in magna fringilla, vel sodales lectus feugiat. Donec sodales, odio eget dictum scelerisque, urna massa fringilla quam, nec pharetra erat dui at massa. Maecenas suscipit velit id scelerisque consectetur. Praesent ac egestas enim. Vestibulum nulla turpis, hendrerit nec sodales vitae, congue at felis. Cras auctor ac quam sed fermentum. Quisque libero est, aliquam ac lorem a, semper molestie mi. Cras suscipit eu erat eget hendrerit. In in erat eu eros volutpat bibendum sit amet fermentum enim. Vestibulum dictum orci sed tincidunt posuere. Donec viverra nunc ut sem viverra, et vestibulum mauris feugiat. Donec imperdiet quam dui, vitae vehicula ipsum hendrerit non. Phasellus nec augue eu erat posuere varius in quis odio. Nunc justo turpis, scelerisque non leo vel, laoreet ornare neque. Donec a neque ac nibh ultricies tristique id vel magna. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque viverra ante in magna fringilla, vel sodales lectus feugiat. Donec sodales, odio eget dictum scelerisque, urna massa fringilla quam, nec pharetra erat dui at massa. Maecenas suscipit velit id scelerisque consectetur. Praesent ac egestas enim. Vestibulum nulla turpis, hendrerit nec sodales vitae, congue at felis. Cras auctor ac quam sed fermentum. Quisque libero est, aliquam ac lorem a, semper molestie mi. Cras suscipit eu erat eget hendrerit. In in erat eu eros volutpat bibendum sit amet fermentum enim. Vestibulum dictum orci sed tincidunt posuere. Donec viverra nunc ut sem viverra, et vestibulum mauris feugiat. Donec imperdiet quam dui, vitae vehicula ipsum hendrerit non. Phasellus nec augue eu erat posuere varius in quis odio. Nunc justo turpis, scelerisque non leo vel, laoreet ornare neque. Donec a neque ac nibh ultricies tristique id vel magna. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque viverra ante in magna fringilla, vel sodales lectus feugiat. Donec sodales, odio eget dictum scelerisque, urna massa fringilla quam, nec pharetra erat dui at massa. Maecenas suscipit velit id scelerisque consectetur. Praesent ac egestas enim. Vestibulum nulla turpis, hendrerit nec sodales vitae, congue at felis. Cras auctor ac quam sed fermentum. Quisque libero est, aliquam ac lorem a, semper molestie mi. Cras suscipit eu erat eget hendrerit. 
              </h3>
          </div>
          <div class = "flex2"></div>
      </div>
  </body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
```